# Import data from Excel 2007 to SQL Server 2008 (two relational tables)

Tags: sql-server-2008, import, excel-2007

I've just run the import wizard from SSMS and created an SSIS package for one table. What I really need though is to be able to import 32 columns from my spreadsheet into one parent table, and then 1 additional column to a separate table that is tied to the parent table by the parent table's ID.

So after the first 32 columns are imported as a row, I need to fetch that row's newly inserted ID and then add the 33rd column to the other table along with the id from the parent table. Is this doable with the import wizard in SSMS or do I need to do something more fancy with SSIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just importing all of the data to a staging table and then wrote a sproc to select the initial columns for my parent table, getting the scope identity, and pumping in the last column to the related table.  Would be cool to be able to do this in one shot, but I ran out of time and had to just get it done.